# Is it possible to have "not in/exists" in one table then in another table?

Tags: t-sql

I'm now maintaining a big app somebody else wrote mining some data from some big government legacy systems.  Basically I need a single query result to populate a gridview that takes each part number from a Tech Order and counts matching part numbers in the Fedlog table. If none found then look in the "commercial" table.  The existing query currently only looks in the Fedlog table and reads as follows:

```
select p.*,
 (select case when count(*) > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end as SL
  from tbl_fedlog where [Part Number] = p.[Part Number]) as SL
from tbl_pcms p 
where  p.[Tech Order] = '0B-E0C-9' order by p.Figure, p.[Index], p.Indenture
```

When 'N' I've got to look in the commerical table.  Could I have some suggestion on the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

What should the result look like for the 'N' scenario - just another 'Y'/'N' answer? If so, you should be able to simply replace the 'N' expression with another scalar query against the "commercial" table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `UNION ALL` between a Fedlog query and a commercial query, that checks each for existence:

```
SELECT p.*
, SL = 'Y'
, part_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_fedlog WHERE [Part Number] = p.[Part Number])
from tbl_pcms p 
where  p.[Tech Order] = '0B-E0C-9'
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_fedlog WHERE [Part Number] = p.[Part Number])

UNION ALL

SELECT p.*
, SL = 'Y'
, part_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_commercial WHERE [Part Number] = p.[Part Number])
from tbl_pcms p 
where  p.[Tech Order] = '0B-E0C-9'
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_commercial WHERE [Part Number] = p.[Part Number])
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_fedlog WHERE [Part Number] = p.[Part Number])
```

I would need more info to address the 'N' scenario mentioned in other answer though.

Answer (score 0):

If the logic is to display `'Y'` when the part exists in either the `Fedlog` or the `Commercial` table and `'N'` otherwise, then you could try grouping & aggregating those tables separately and (outer-)joining the aggregated result sets to `tbl_pcms`, like this:

```
SELECT
  p.*,
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(f.PartCount, c.PartCount) IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS SL
FROM tbl_pcms p

  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      [Part Number],
      COUNT(*) AS PartCount
    FROM tbl_fedlog
    GROUP BY [Part Number]
  ) f ON p.[Part Number] = f.[Part Number]

  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      [Part Number],
      COUNT(*) AS PartCount
    FROM tbl_commercial
    GROUP BY [Part Number]
  ) c ON p.[Part Number] = c.[Part Number]

WHERE p.[Tech Order] = '0B-E0C-9'
ORDER BY
  p.Figure,
  p.[Index],
  p.Indenture
```